# R: How to calculate IRF knowing VAR coefficients

Tags: var

I used a different approach to estimate the VAR coefficients, and now I ended up with a K=2, p=3 VAR model. As the VAR model is not a result returned by the var function, I can't use it as an input for irf().

My questions are:

1. How can I compute the irf using the VAR coefficients?
2. How can I plot the IRF with 95% confidence interval?

Thank you!